# Using Drop Down Lists to filter ListView with SQL Datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on a website that is active right now (www.jocogolocal.com), and one feature that is needed to enhance the site is, rather than using buttons to sort the list of vendors, to use drop down lists specifically for the City and Vendor Typeto filter the ListView to show only those with the active filters. The issue is that it being a ListView with a datasource, every time I try calling to the elements inside the ListView I recieve an error message stating "Operator was null", referring to the City label underneath a Vendor.

I tried using an event from the Drop Down List (OnSelectedIndexChange) to try to solve my issue, but it always comes back to the operator being null when trying to access an attribute inside the ListView.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="livVendor"
    DataKeyNames="VendorID" 
    DataSourceID="sdsListViewVendor" 
    InsertItemPosition="FirstItem"
    >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Table runat="server" Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="12px">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCityTest" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="City" />&nbsp
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCity" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bargersville">Bargersville</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Carthage">Carthage</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Franklin">Franklin</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Greenfield">Greenfield</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Greenwood">Greenwood</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Indianapolis">Indianapolis</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Roanoke">Roanoke</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Trafalgar">Trafalgar</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Whiteland">Whiteland</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Vendor Type" />&nbsp
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlVendorType" DataSourceID="sdsDropDownListVendorType" DataTextField="VendorType" DataValueField="VendorTypeID" AutoPostBack="true" />&nbsp
                                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandArgument="Name" CommandName="Sort"  />&nbsp
                                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandArgument="City" CommandName="Sort" Text="City" />&nbsp
                                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandArgument="VendorType" CommandName="Sort" Text="Vendor Type" />&nbsp
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text="<br /> <br />"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                    </table>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-auto">
                <p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Enabled="false" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'/></p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server"  ID="lblVendorType" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Bind("VendorType") %>' />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAddress" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCity" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'/>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblState" Enabled="false"  Text='<%# Bind("State") %>' />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblZipCode" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Bind("ZipCode") %>'/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPhoneNumber" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Bind("PhoneNumber") %>'/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypWebsite" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Website") %>' Text='<%# Bind("Website") %>' />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDescription" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypLocate" Text="Locate" CssClass="button" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Name", "https://google.com/maps/search/ {0}") + " " + Eval("Address") + " " + Eval("City") + " " + Eval("State") + " " + Eval("Zipcode") %>' />

                </div>
                <br /><br /><br />
            </td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<br /><br />
```

I expect the DropDownLists to show only the Vendors that has the same attribute as selected on the DropDownList filters. Any help would be highly appreciated

### Edit:

Here is the coe in the ViewVendor.cs file of what I am trying to at least test:

```
    }

    protected void ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindData((livVendor.FindControl("ddlCity") as DropDownList).SelectedValue);
    }

    protected void bindData(string userChoice)
    {
        Label lblCity = livVendor.FindControl("lblCity") as Label;
        DropDownList ddlCity = livVendor.FindControl("ddlCity") as DropDownList;
        ddlCity.DataSource = sdsDropDownListCity;
        lblCity.DataBind();
        lblCity.Text = ddlCity.SelectedValue;


    }
}
```

}

Here, I am checking to see if I could at least access lblCity to change it to the selected value, but everytime I execute ddlCity_SelectedValue, I get the error message: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', so if I can not get this part to work, what are the chances that I can filter the listview to display only vendors with the selected value?

Comment: if you could provide the code what have you done after trigger the OnSelectedIndexChanged in your .cs file. I can give you more specific help.

Comment: I have provided the code from the .cs file that I am trying to do. In regards to your post, I am unsure what I can use from it to filter the ListView control.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your problem. I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I really needed to do was to manipulate the DataSource.SelectCommand from the .cs file, as such:

```
    protected void ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlCity = livVendor.FindControl("ddlCity") as DropDownList;
        sdsListViewVendor.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Vendor, VendorType WHERE VendorType.VendorTypeID = Vendor.VendorTypeID AND Vendor.City = '" + ddlCity.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY Name";
```

This can also be used for my other drop down lists to manipulate the ListView. Thank you to user 劉鎮瑲 and others for their contribution.